# Compiling x32 bit LD_PRELOAD on 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: c++, compilation, 64-bit, ld-preload

I'm trying to compile x32 LD_PRELOAD on x64 platform(Ubuntu), my command:

```
g++ -fPIC -m32  -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -ldl -o test.so test.cpp
```

But i'm getting error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can i fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: You are probably missing some multilib package, or your 32-bit standard C++ library is not in the lib path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install 32-bit development packages provided by your distribution.  You are seeing this error because you do not have a 32-bit libstdc++ to link against.

Try installing Ubuntu's `g++-multilib` package.